# how to delete wine temp files for an application

Tags: wine

I have been using ultrasurf a proxy server through wine.
And yesterday ultrsurf was easting too much memory so I killed it via console. Then I restarted again and it wouldn't start saying some error. I deleted it and the files it created in the same directory(it's a portable version) and re-downloaded and tried to execute but it shows the same error.

So I tried to use it by running `wine u1204.exe` as root(I know its not recommended) wine created .wine directory for root and it started working fine!

so what I could understand from this is when I killed ultrasurf it messed up with some files or temp files of wine and it won't start now! So If I can remove those temp files I can run ultrasurf again from normal user. Thaks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete or rename your wine profile directory. The default wine profile directory is located in your home: `~/.wine`. Delete or rename that directory and wine will create a new profile directory. The effect is similar to reinstalling windows. Note that all your settings and other customization in wine will be gone too.

You can set up a per application wine profile like this:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/wine/someapp/profile wine ~/wine/someapp/someapp.exe
```

Comment: but I have other applications installed through wine like ansys, I have not customized much but I have to install it again.. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: the other alternative would be to actually find out what exactly went wrong and fix that. you said you killed the wine process, that would be similar to cutting the power to a windows machine. it could be a corrupt file or corrupt registry entry. i asume your windows apps are closed source. troubleshooting closed source apps is really really hard. that is why i use gnu/linux.

Comment: @pahnin follow lesmana's advice by using a custom `WINEPREFIX` for `u1204.exe`, for example with `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-u1204 wine u1204.exe`. That way you won't lose you remaining wine settings, but the settings of `u1204.exe` will live in a different directory. If it breaks again, you can just delete `~/.wine-u1204` which will reset only the settings of `u1204.exe`. You can create a custom starter so don't always have to use the console to launch it.